# SP2007 how can I create an alert for all pending "page change" approvals

Tags: 2007

We have a small SP2007 environment, and when a user edits a page, approval is required. But there's no alert, so the user has to call the admin and share it's location.

How can I setup an alert so that all approvals from all teamsites go to the same person?

Answer (score 0):

Use the alert functionality on the document library where the pages are created. Select the useraccount of the approver. After you do this, the approver will be triggered after each update of a page.

See also [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918#Pick_tab=2007) documentation.

[image: alert]

Comment: Will I need to do this for all team sites individually or can I turn this on for all sites from the top level somewhere?

Comment: Yes you need to do this manual on library/list level.